# Ubuntu 14.04 / iRedMail - SMTP Error (451): Failed to add recipient

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I am facing strange problem after today.

For months i am using iRedMail 0.9.2 and i have no problems at all. I received and send email all the way until today.

Today i install `apt-get install sendmail` and everything stopped working.

Now i can not receive and send emails.

So i menaged to remove sendmail and reinstall postfix but now in Roundcube when i try to send email i receive the following error:

```
SMTP Error (451): Failed to add recipient "theemail@gmail.com" (4.3.0 <office@superweb.bg>: Temporary lookup failure).
```

I removed sendmail and reinstalled postfix like this:

```
sudo apt-get purge sendmail
sudo apt-get install --reinstall postfix
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

Here is what my mail.log says:

```
Oct  5 18:13:58 mail postfix/cleanup[3300]: warning: B8CB3A22AD7: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Oct  5 18:13:58 mail postfix/pickup[3297]: warning: maildrop/BAEC8A22ACD: error writing B8CB3A22AD7: queue file write error
Oct  5 18:14:41 mail postfix/smtpd[3318]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pcre
Oct  5 18:14:42 mail postfix/smtpd[3318]: connect from smtp-out.abv.bg[194.153.145.80]
Oct  5 18:14:42 mail postfix/proxymap[3303]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf is unavailable. unsupported dictionary type: mysql
Oct  5 18:14:42 mail postfix/trivial-rewrite[3301]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf: table lookup problem
Oct  5 18:14:42 mail postfix/trivial-rewrite[3301]: warning: virtual_mailbox_domains lookup failure
Oct  5 18:14:42 mail postfix/trivial-rewrite[3301]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf: table lookup problem
Oct  5 18:14:42 mail postfix/trivial-rewrite[3301]: warning: virtual_mailbox_domains lookup failure
Oct  5 18:14:42 mail postfix/smtpd[3318]: warning: pcre:/etc/postfix/helo_access.pcre is unavailable. unsupported dictionary type: pcre
Oct  5 18:14:42 mail postfix/smtpd[3318]: warning: pcre:/etc/postfix/helo_access.pcre: table lookup problem
Oct  5 18:14:42 mail postfix/smtpd[3318]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from smtp-out.abv.bg[194.153.145.80]: 451 4.3.5 <smtp-out.abv.bg>: Helo command rejected: Server configuration error;$
Oct  5 18:14:42 mail postfix/smtpd[3318]: disconnect from smtp-out.abv.bg[194.153.145.80]
Oct  5 18:14:58 mail postfix/pickup[3297]: B1974A22AD7: uid=0 from=<root>
Oct  5 18:14:42 mail postfix/proxymap[3303]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf is unavailable. unsupported dictionary type: mysql
Oct  5 18:14:58 mail postfix/proxymap[3303]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf is unavailable. unsupported dictionary type: mysql
Oct  5 18:14:58 mail postfix/cleanup[3300]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf lookup error for "root@mail.vivashost.com"
Oct  5 18:14:58 mail postfix/cleanup[3300]: warning: B1974A22AD7: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Oct  5 18:14:58 mail postfix/pickup[3297]: warning: maildrop/BAEC8A22ACD: error writing B1974A22AD7: queue file write error
Oct  5 18:15:58 mail postfix/pickup[3297]: C0A32A22AD7: uid=0 from=<root>
Oct  5 18:15:58 mail postfix/cleanup[3300]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf lookup error for "root@mail.vivashost.com"
Oct  5 18:15:58 mail postfix/cleanup[3300]: warning: C0A32A22AD7: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Oct  5 18:15:58 mail postfix/pickup[3297]: warning: maildrop/BAEC8A22ACD: error writing C0A32A22AD7: queue file write error
Oct  5 18:16:27 mail postfix/smtpd[3395]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pcre
Oct  5 18:16:27 mail postfix/smtpd[3395]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Oct  5 18:15:58 mail postfix/proxymap[3303]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf is unavailable. unsupported dictionary type: mysql
Oct  5 18:16:27 mail postfix/proxymap[3303]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf is unavailable. unsupported dictionary type: mysql
Oct  5 18:16:27 mail postfix/trivial-rewrite[3301]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf: table lookup problem
Oct  5 18:16:27 mail postfix/trivial-rewrite[3301]: warning: virtual_mailbox_domains lookup failure
Oct  5 18:16:27 mail postfix/trivial-rewrite[3301]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf: table lookup problem
Oct  5 18:16:27 mail postfix/trivial-rewrite[3301]: warning: virtual_mailbox_domains lookup failure
Oct  5 18:16:27 mail postfix/smtpd[3395]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 451 4.3.0 <office@superweb.bg>: Temporary lookup failure; from=<office@superweb.bg> to=<th$
Oct  5 18:16:27 mail roundcube: <65kuug0v> SMTP Error: Failed to add recipient 'thelex@abv.bg'. 4.3.0 <office@superweb.bg>: Temporary lookup failure (Code: 451) in /opt/www/roundcub$
Oct  5 18:16:27 mail postfix/smtpd[3395]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Oct  5 18:16:58 mail postfix/pickup[3297]: 508F3A22AD9: uid=0 from=<root>
Oct  5 18:16:27 mail postfix/proxymap[3303]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf is unavailable. unsupported dictionary type: mysql
Oct  5 18:16:58 mail postfix/proxymap[3303]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf is unavailable. unsupported dictionary type: mysql
Oct  5 18:16:58 mail postfix/cleanup[3300]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf lookup error for "root@mail.vivashost.com"
Oct  5 18:16:58 mail postfix/cleanup[3300]: warning: 508F3A22AD9: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Oct  5 18:16:58 mail postfix/pickup[3297]: warning: maildrop/BAEC8A22ACD: error writing 508F3A22AD9: queue file write error
```

Can you help me out resolve this problem. I think i have wrong configuration for my postfix.

Can you help me out resolve the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `unsupported dictionary type: mysql` Looks like you are missing the MySQL extension for postfix, available in package `postfix-mysql`.

Comment: Thanks i found it just after i post my question. It was the problem. Thanks once again :)

Comment: Ok, great it worked. I created an answer with the solution I proposed in the comment above. Please accept it, so the question will be marked as *solved*.

Answer (score 1):

```
warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf is unavailable. unsupported dictionary type: mysql
```

This is most probably due to the missing extension for postfix providing mysql lookup support. In most distributions / package managers the package is called `postfix-mysql`, so e.g.:

```
apt-get install postfix-mysql
```

Answer (score -2):

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/smtp-451-error-temporary-local-problem-please-try-later.221212/

Did you update the nameservers for the domains after the move? Do the domains resolve to that new server?